# REST API for rabbitmq

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, rabbitmq, amqp

Is there a way how can I send data to RabbitMQ from $.ajax?

My application is made up of several thousands web-clients (written on js) and WCF REST service and now I am trying to figure out how can I create a scalable point for my application. The idea is to have a rabbitmq instance which receives messages from js clients placed on one side, and instances of WCF Workflow Services which are taking pending messages from the queue.

I understand that AMQP and HTTP is pretty different things.

So the question is - is there a REST interface for rabbit mq or some sort of gateway for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lots of 3rd-party HTTP plugins listed on RabbitMQ's [developer tools page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html), and they also offer an [experimental JSON-RPC plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html#experimental) that allows for AMQP over HTTP access.

You should also take a look at [RabbitJS](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/11/12/rabbitmq-nodejs-rabbitjs/) and [SockJS](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/13/sockjs-websocket-emulation/) to see what the Rabbit team is doing to bring messaging to the worlds of node.js and WebSockets, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The RabbitMQ REST API documentation for the 3.7.4 release can be found here:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.4/priv/www/api/index.html

It also allows to publish messages besides management tasks.

Important note from the linked documentation:

> Please note that the publish / get paths in the HTTP API are intended
> for injecting test messages, diagnostics etc - they do not implement
> reliable delivery and so should be treated as a sysadmin's tool rather
> than a general API for messaging.

Comment: What you pointed out above is RabbitMQ Management Plugin's bundled HTTP API, which is essentially a RESTful API. However, it doesn't implement reliable messaging delivery so it's probably not a good idea to use it in production systems. Here is the quote: "Please note that the publish / get paths in the HTTP API are intended for injecting test messages, diagnostics etc - they do not implement reliable delivery and so should be treated as a sysadmin's tool rather than a general API for messaging."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel plugin which you can research at [RabbitMQ Plugins](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html)

It looks as though it provides AMQP over HTTP with JSON.