# Using ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ simultaneously

Tags: java, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, messagebroker

According to my experience in working with message brokers, RabbitMq has a better performance under heavy loads. However, for the sake of simplicity, it is better to use AtiveMQ in the browser. I want to know if it is possible to use both of them simultaneously?
Moreover, is there any way for me to send a message using ActiveMQ in the browser and receive the same message using RabbitMQ in the server side?
I will be appreciate if any one suggest me a useful sample code.

Comment: create a `service` that reads from `ActiveMQ` and writes to `RabbitMQ`... I can't be hard right?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the browser" ? You don't run ActiveMQ in a browser.

Comment: @nafas Let me explain it more clearly by an example. Sometimes in my project I need to send or receive a message in the browser. So, it is better for me using ActiveMQ as a message broker by Ajax which is supported by ActiveMQ. But when it comes to processes with more than 5000 transaction per second, RabbitMQ has better performance. Consequently, I need using both of them at the same time. Now, I wanna know if it is possible using both of them in my project. In addition, is there any possibility for me to send a message with RabbitMQ in the server and receive it by ActiveMQ in the browser.

Comment: @nos Assume a situation which ActiveMQ run in the server and browser can send or receive messages by Ajax.

Comment: @Reza Well, you can access RabbitMQ in different ways too if you want from the browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080718/rest-api-for-rabbitmq , it seems odd to use AciveMQ if its only purpose is to be a frontend for browsers that you then pass into RabbitMQ. You'd want to think twice about directly exposing RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ to a browser though, people would start throwing a lot of junk at your messaging service.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ can speak AMQP 1.0, RabbitMQ can speak AMQP 1.0 using this [plug-in](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0) .
You could create a bridge using this protocol.

**But** reading your question, I think you don't need ActiveMQ.
In order to send the message to the browser you can use [webstomp plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html).

Comment: >> I will be appreciate if any one suggest me a useful sample code. <<  Your answer is not much useful.

Comment: What  kind of the code are you looking for?
with `amqp` you can create a bridge send/receive. with `stomp` you can send and receive the message using `JS`.

Comment: any example or tips about bridge implementation. I worked with rabbitmq and still can't imagine anything, but a java client that will re-transmit messages. (feels inefficient though)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is implement a bridge pattern. Now although the JMS bridges were typically 
created to provide a mechanism between JMS message providers, the Integration pattern can be used for wire protocols as well.

So if you are trying to send messages between ActiveMQ - RabbitMQ here's the potential options:

1) ActiveMQ - Defacto JMS support, AMQP, STOMP is also supported
2) RabbitMQ - Defacto STOMP support, AMQP is also supported along with other popular wire protocols like MQTT

So when it comes to bridging options:

a) [1] JMS              -- [2] STOMP (or) AMQP
b) [1] AMQP (or) STOMP  -- [2] AMQP  (or)  STOMP

In the case of the 1'st and 2nd bridge options, the easiest way to implement is by using an Apache QPID client.

Alternately for most robust configurations, It's better to implement as a Spring Integration Channel or a Camel Route.

Here's a snippet on how to acheive this with Spring Integration:

```
<beans:bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <beans:property name="environment">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiTemplate">
            <beans:ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jndiName">
            <beans:value>ConnectionFactory</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Channels and adapters for SI -->

    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" destination-name="myJmsQueue" channel="rabbitChannel"/>
      <channel id="rabbitChannel"/>
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="rabbitChannel" exchange-name="fromJmsExchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"/>

    <!-- Connectivity to Rabbit -->

    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="cf"/>
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="cf" host="localhost"/>

    <!-- Rabbit entities, to be created at context startup -->

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="cf"/>
     <rabbit:queue name="fromJMS"/>
     <rabbit:direct-exchange name="fromJmsExchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="fromJMS"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
     </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

Article Source :  http://integrationsphere.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/bridging-between-jms-and-rabbitmq-amqp.html